# Run a cron job every 45 minute only between 10 am to 10 pm

Tags: cron

I need my crontab to execute every 45 minute of hour between 10 am to 10 pm.
currently I trying this

*/45 10-21 * * *

is this right or not?

Answer (score 0):

This would start the first job at 10:45am last one at 9:45pm and jobs started at 45th min of every hour in between.

You can refer here how cron works https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html